# change table format of the output

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pandas

I would like to change the format of my output for the following code.

```
import pandas as pd

x= pd.read_csv('x.csv')
y= pd.read_csv('y.csv')
z= pd.read_csv('z.csv')
list = pd.merge(x, y, how='left', on=['xx'])
list = pd.merge(list, z, how='left', on=['xx'])
columns_to_keep =  ['yy','zz', 'uu']
list = list.set_index(['xx'])
list = list[columns_to_keep]
list = list.sort_index(axis=0, level=None, ascending=True, inplace=False, 
                                   sort_remaining=True, by=None)
with open('write.csv','w') as f:
    list.to_csv(f,header=True, index=True, index_label='xx')
```

from this:

id   date   user_id   user_name

1   8/13/2007   1   a1

2   1/8/2007    2   a2

2   1/8/2007    3   a3

3   12/14/2007  4   a4

4   3/6/2008    5   a5

4   4/14/2009   6   a6

4   5/30/2008   7   a7

4   5/30/2008   8   a8

5   6/17/2007   9   a9

to this:

id  date    user_id user_name

1   8/13/2007   1   a1

2   1/8/2007    2;3 a2;a3

3   12/14/2007  4   a4

4   3/6/2008    5;6;7;8 a5;a6;a7;a8

5   6/17/2007   9   a9

Comment: Can you share input files x, y , z ?

Comment: hey @MaheshKaria I'm not able to post the tables in the correct format. I even tried https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/ to. do you have any suggestions?

Comment: no need to put tables just open csv file in noiedpad++ and paste it, that will be sufficient.

Comment: Table x: user_id,id
1,1
2,2
3,2
4,3
5,4
6,4
7,4
8,4
9,5

Comment: Table y: user_id,user_name
1,a1
2,a2
3,a3
4,a4
5,a5
6,a6
7,a7
8,a8
9,a9

Comment: Table z: id,date
1,10/7/2015
2,12/3/2012
2,12/3/2012
3,11/24/2014
4,2/10/2016
4,2/10/2016
4,2/10/2016
4,2/10/2016
5,12/1/2014

Answer (score 0):

I think the following should work on the final dataframe (list), though I would suggest not to use "list" as a name as it is a built in function in python and you might want to use that function somewhere else. So in my code I will use "df" instead of "list":

```
ind = list(set(df.index.get_values()))
finaldf = pd.DataFrame(columns = list(df.columns))
for val in ind:
tempDF = df.loc[val]
print tempDF
for i in range(tempDF.shape[0]):
    for jloc,j in enumerate(list(df.columns)):
        if i != 0 and j != 'date':
            finaldf.loc[val,j] += (";"+str(tempDF.iloc[i,jloc]))
        elif i == 0:
            finaldf.loc[val,j] = str(tempDF.iloc[i,jloc])
print finaldf
```